# Selecting comment above the DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a question. I've got this HTML:

[image]

I press a button (which is the 'editcurrent' class) which makes something appear. That works all, but I want to check which comment is above the control-group, I want to get the value of the comment so I can decide what I want to show to the user. But how do i get this value, with closest or parent? (i'm using jQuery)

I got this code:

```
var comments = $('.form-horizontal').contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType===8; })
```

this gives me all the comments of the form. But I don't really know how to use the closest method with searching for comments.

```
console.log($(this).closest('.control-group').children(this.nodeType===8));
```

This is obviously not working... Could someone help me out?

Comment: Please copy and paste your actual HTML, don't post *pictures* of your HTML. It make it much harder for people to give you answers they've tested.

Comment: Sorry Will use HTML in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use jQuery to *select* comment nodes, but you can use it to select the `.control-group` and work backward from there, as the comment will be its previous sibling (probably with a whitespace text node in there, depending on the markup):

```js
var node = $(".form-horizontal .control-group")[0];
while (node && node.nodeType != Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
  node = node.previousSibling;
}
alert(node ?  node.nodeValue : "Not found");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend></legend>
    <!-- Multiple Radios -->
    <div class="control-group">
      ....
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer, in combination with the comment from Satpal. I said it to solution within 8 minutes! Thanks